# Google Apps Script - RegEx works on small text but not on large file?

Tags: html, regex, google-apps-script, web-scraping

I am trying to make a simple Ebay price scraper function in Apps Script for use in Google Sheets:

```js
// This code produces a null result (not correct)
function GetEbayPriceByISBN(isbn = 9780765377135)
{
    const ebayUrl = 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=' + isbn + '&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&_odkw=' + isbn + '&LH_Complete=1&LH_Sold=1'
    let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(ebayUrl)
    let htmlStr = response.getContentText()

    const priceSpan = /<span class="s-item__price"><!--F#f_0--><!--F#f_0--><span class="POSITIVE">([\s\S]*?)<!--F\/--><!--F\/--><\/span>/gm;
    let allPrices = htmlStr.match(priceSpan)

    console.log(allPrices)

    return allPrices;
}
```

The regex above is the best I can come up with to pull the exact data I need. It works perfectly [here](https://regex101.com/r/MsGMLE/1), but when I run the code, it **fails**. I get null from `xmlStr.match(priceSpan)` when matching against the full HTML file, when it should give me a list of all the occurances of that span.

I do get the **correct** result when testing against a smaller snippet of the HTML file however:

```js
// This code WORKS
function GetEbayPriceByISBN2(isbn = 9780765377135)
{
    const testText = `</span><span class="clipped"> - Mistborn: The Final Empire - Paperback By Sanderson, Brandon - VERY GOOD</span></span></a></div><div class="s-item__details clearfix"><div class="s-item__detail s-item__detail--primary"><span class="s-item__price"><!--F#f_0--><!--F#f_0--><span class="POSITIVE">$5.00</span><!--F/--><!--F/--></span></div><span class="s-item__detail s-item__detail--secondary"><span class="s-item__seller-info"><span class="s-item__seller-info-text">gilsdorf (48) 100%</span></span></span>`

    const priceSpan = /<span class="s-item__price"><!--F#f_0--><!--F#f_0--><span class="POSITIVE">([\s\S]*?)<!--F\/--><!--F\/--><\/span>/gm;
    let allPrices = testText.match(priceSpan)

    console.log(allPrices)

    return allPrices;
}
```

so I dont think there's anything exactly wrong with the regex. My knowledge of Apps Script and parsing web pages is minimal, so I may be doing things completely wrong.

Any Ideas? Thanks.

**Note**: I have tried using a simpler regex `s-item__price` and this **does work** (it finds all instances of 's-item__price'), however as soon as I add quotations to my regex (escaped or not), it fails.

Comment: If the regex works against some toy example texts and does not work with the real source, you either 1) have a different text, not actually of the type you used for test 2) the text is not obtained in the code (make sure you actually have the right text inside the variable by printing to console.)

Comment: And just an idea: are there whitespaces between tags in real text? Are there more than one space between tag names and attributes? Any other whitespace differencies? Are there single or double quotes wrapping attribute values? If yes, try `/<span\s+class=["']s-item__price["']>\s*<!--F#f_0-->\s*<!--F#f_0--><span\s+class=["']POSITIVE["']>([\s\S]*?)<!--F\/-->\s*<!--F\/-->\s*<\/span>/i`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, I have printed out the source and it does contain what I need. The full HTML text is [here](https://regex101.com/r/MsGMLE/1) if you want to look. Also when I use a smaller regex I can find all the values but not in the format I need (see the note).

Edit: The regex you supplied didn't seem to make any difference unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

When I check the HTML using the URL in your script, I noticed that the retrieved HTML is as follows.

```html
<span class=s-item__price><!--F#f_0--><!--F#f_0--><span class=POSITIVE>$29.95</span><!--F/--><!--F/--></span>
```

It seems that `s-item__price` and `POSITIVE` are not enclosed by `"`. But, in your script, the following regex is used.

```html
<span class="s-item__price"><!--F#f_0--><!--F#f_0--><span class="POSITIVE">([\s\S]*?)<!--F\/--><!--F\/--><\/span>
```

In this case, the above value cannot be retrieved. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue. When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function GetEbayPriceByISBN(isbn = 9780765377135) {
  const ebayUrl = 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=' + isbn + '&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&_odkw=' + isbn + '&LH_Complete=1&LH_Sold=1';
  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(ebayUrl);
  let htmlStr = response.getContentText();

  const priceSpan = /<span class=s-item__price><!--F#f_0--><!--F#f_0--><span class=POSITIVE>([\s\S]*?)<!--F\/--><!--F\/--><\/span>/gm; // Modified

  let allPrices = htmlStr.match(priceSpan);
  console.log(allPrices);
  return allPrices;
}
```

- When this modified script is run, the following result is obtained.

  ```
  [
    "<span class=s-item__price><!--F#f_0--><!--F#f_0--><span class=POSITIVE>$29.95</span><!--F/--><!--F/--></span>",
    "<span class=s-item__price><!--F#f_0--><!--F#f_0--><span class=POSITIVE>$5.22</span><!--F/--><!--F/--></span>",
    "<span class=s-item__price><!--F#f_0--><!--F#f_0--><span class=POSITIVE>$13.22</span><!--F/--><!--F/--></span>",
    "<span class=s-item__price><!--F#f_0--><!--F#f_0--><span class=POSITIVE>$7.69</span><!--F/--><!--F/--></span>",
    "<span class=s-item__price><!--F#f_0--><!--F#f_0--><span class=POSITIVE>$5.00</span><!--F/--><!--F/--></span>"
  ]
  ```
- For example, if there is also a pattern that `s-item__price` and `POSITIVE` are enclosed by `"`, how about the following modification?

  - From

    ```
      const priceSpan = /<span class=s-item__price><!--F#f_0--><!--F#f_0--><span class=POSITIVE>([\s\S]*?)<!--F\/--><!--F\/--><\/span>/gm;
    ```
  - To

    ```
      const priceSpan = /<span class="?s-item__price"?><!--F#f_0--><!--F#f_0--><span class="?POSITIVE"?>([\s\S]*?)<!--F\/--><!--F\/--><\/span>/gm;
    ```

Comment: Fascinating. The html I've been using and testing against **does** have the quotes. You can even see them in the [regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/MsGMLE/1) from above. I'm not sure why that is, but indeed if I remove all the quotes like you say, it works flawlessly. Thanks!

Comment: @Nebulous39 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When the HTML is retrieved using UrlFetchApp, the HTML is retrieved without running Javascript. If your HTML is retrieved using your browser, the HTML is retrieved with running Javascript. I guessed that this might have been the reason for your issue. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.